Best way to connect two wifi routers (one router has two WANs) that would share one WAN source ending up with two different LANs with different pswds
The reason I'm wanting to do this is I've got a rental on the property and I want the rental unit to have its own wifi router LAN that is different from mine.  But I only want to use one WAN source (input).  Another benefit to this is I'm (and my tenant) are getting more Ethernet ports (2 WAN & 4 LAN-ASUS and 1 WAN & 4 LAN on the D-Link) to use than if I just used the new ASUS and the guest setup with the bonus of a more secure two router system!
I'm thinking on purchasing the ASUS RT-AX86U Pro (AX5700) Dual Band WiFi 6 Extendable Gaming Router, 2.5G Port, Gaming Port, Mobile Game Mode, Port Forwarding, Subscription-free Network Security, VPN, AiMesh Compatible as MY wifi/router and an older D-Link DIR-842 wifi/router as the 2nd LAN
Since the ASUS has two WANs, can I use the 2nd WAN to connect to the D-link WAN to create two separate LANs with their own users and passwords?
If so, is it straight forward or do I have to tweak some settings on one or both wifi/routers?
Additional concern:  Will connecting these two wifi routers degrade the networking speed etc?

can I use the 2nd WAN to connect to the D-link WAN to create two separate LAN - no. WAN to WAN makes no sense, seeing as WAN, in layman's terms, is how you connect to "the internet"

WAN is for ISP connections from a modem only - connecting two routers is done via LAN ports, however when firewalling the second router it'll create an issue because it will be double-NAT'd, meaning the primary router will need to be accessed to configure game systems and any other devices that require port forwarding (UPnP shouldn't be used (there's no secure implementation of it), and configuring a DMZ isn't ideal either since it bypasses the statefull firewall of the router, which is what makes a router a router). Best solution: have tenant get their own internet service

(Cont'd...) A tenant's router in control of a landlord isn't recommended since it's a violation of privacy, creating legal exposure and liability for the landlord (no tenant wants their landlord to have access to their router if explained what that actually means - none of their data is secure at that point). This type of scenario simply should not be done for reasons important to both the landlord and the tenant because it's a liability for both. The only secure implementation of this would be to have the tenant have their own router behind the two existing ones, making it triple NAT'd.

I feel you may be overthinking this. Without knowing all the details such as the modem you will be using to connect to your provider. The Dual WAN may not accomplish what you are thinking. A Dual WAN is typically a Fail-Over. In which case you would have two service providers lets say one providing Fiber another Cable. Or one providing Cable and other DSL. With the Dual WAN should your primary provider become unserviceable for a time it will reroute the connection to your secondary provider automatically. There are multitudes of routers with multitudes of firmware and features and some may allow port reconfiguration to allow what I am imagining of your expectations from your description.
If your provider is Cable or Fiber, most offer multi-port modems or routers. Most Docsis3+ Modems have a 2 or 4port solution built in as well as wireless. My Fiber unit has 8 ports and wireless. I find the wireless is often subpar.
So Here is what I would suggest. Hopefully what you get from your service provider has 2 - 4 ethernet ports. Turn off the wifi and use only the ethernet ports. Connect your first wireless router to a port on the modem and go through the setup of that router and set its IP to be unique. It can be anything as it is an internal IP. Lets say its default is 192.168.10.1, then do something like 192.168.85.1 or anything not the default. After completing setup do the same thing with the second router after plugging it into one of the other ports on your modem again giving it a unique IP.
Both routers will function independently using your modem as the primary gateway.
Good Luck

This isn't a complete answer since it doesn't cover NAT, specifically being double-NAT'd on the second router. Privacy and liability concerns also abate since none of the tenants data is secure if a landlord maintains access to their router, making it a liability for both the landlord and the tenant. The only secure implementation of this would be to have the tenant have their own router behind the two existing ones, making it triple NAT'd.

You should consider just getting a second internet connection, (ideally in the tenants name) for two reasons:

If the tenant does something nefarious (torrenting or worse), if your connections are totally isolated (the tenant doesn't have access to yours and you cant access theres) it's clear who did it.
Each connection will have its own public IP address, hence each person can manage any port forwarding required.


If you don't get a second connection.
It's usually the case that the only way to get multiple IP's is to upgrade to a business plan (read: typically more expensive for the same speed as the comparable residential plan). Hence the only "no additional monthly cost" option is typically to chain the routers - have the internet connection come into one router and then run a wire to the the other one.
I am going to assume you have a router with an addition (WAN) port and you have patched the router with capable firmware such as OpenWRT.
Given that I would suggest the following configuration for your router:

Connect the internet to WAN1
Run a wire to the tenants room from WAN2.
Connect your devices to the LAN.
Create a bridged network spanning the LAN and and wireless interfaces.
Assign an IP range to your LAN 192.168.1.0/24
Run DNS/DHCP on your LAN.
Set WAN2's IP address to: 192.168.2.1
Setup NAT from the tenants WAN2 to the internet.
Add any port forwards they have asked for.
Do not run DNS/DHCP on WAN2.

NOTE: I have kept the name "WAN2" but with this configuration, it is misnamed it is really LAN2 .
Your tenant then has options:

They can plug your connection into the WAN port on their router and just assign a static IP (192.168.2.2) to their WAN interface (they will also need a default route to 192.168.2.1). Enable NAT on the tenants router and create a new range on the inside (LAN side of the tenants router), for example: 192.168.3.1/24
They can plug the wire into the LAN side of their router - as long as they set the default router (issued by DHCP) to 192.168.2.1 on their router it will work.
They could just buy an access point (they don't need a router) - although it might be easier if you provided them with DHCP services in that case.

The landlords LAN gets protection from the tenant with all three tenant options, because the landlord controls the primary router - hence they control routing between the LAN's - ideally they should block all such routing.
The tenant only gets protection from the landlord accessing their LAN if they choose tenant option #1, however that will require double NAT.
In response to the comment, there is a slight variation on tenant option #1 - you could disable NAT, but continue to firewall on the tenants router - this would require an additional route (for 192.168.3.0/24) on the landlords router.
However to re-iterate my first point I don't recommend connection sharing at all, IMO all these choices are worst than just getting a second connection.

This isn't a complete answer since it doesn't cover NAT, specifically being double-NAT'd on the second router. Privacy concerns (great job for mentioning liability concerns =]) also abate since none of the tenants data is secure if a landlord maintains access to their router, making that a liability for both the landlord and the tenant. The only secure implementation of this would be to have the tenant have their own router behind the two existing ones, making it triple NAT'd if the second router doesn't have its own WAN IP, double NAT'd if it would.

You should first purse the answer given by user MagusISS. My answer is how I used to configure routers before upgrading my equipment. I am now configured as described in MagusISS's answer.
You would not connect the tenant's router to a configured 2nd WAN port on your router. Instead, you would connect tenant's router to a LAN port on your router. The image below was take from the User Guide RT0AX86U PRO Wireless-AX5700 Dual-band Gigabit Router. I believe the instructions shown explain how to block the tenant's router from accessing your LAN, while allowing the tenet access to the WAN.

One possible configuration would be to have your LAN use 192.168.2.X and your tenant's LAN use 192.168.1.X, where X=1 for the gateway and 2-254 other devices. So basically, your IPv4 LAN would use NAT to access the WAN. The tenant's IPv4 LAN would use NAT twice to access the WAN.

This isn't a complete answer since it doesn't cover NAT, specifically being double-NAT'd on the second router, as one sentence isn't sufficient in this instance since the tenant would have no control over the WAN facing router for port forwarding. Privacy and liability concerns also abate since none of the tenants data is secure if a landlord maintains access to their router, making it a liability for both the landlord and the tenant.  The only secure implementation of this would be to have the tenant have their own router behind the two existing ones, making it triple NAT'd.

The risks you speak about are illegal, both civilly and legally - tapping into a tenant's communication lines is normally a felony since it's illegal wiretapping. Entering a tenant's apt is illegal without prior notice, which the tenant has a legal right to be present for, and accessing a tenant's electronic devices while in their home and without their permission would also be illegal (any of these would also allow the tenant to sue for punitive and compensatory damages - often substantial awards, look no further than ISP employees who abused their access to customer routers).

In order for the tenant to access the tenant's router's LAN jacks, the tenant's router would have to reside in the tenant's residence. Similarly, the landlord's router would need reside in the landlord's residence. An ethernet cable would connect the two routers. The traffic between the tenant's router and the WAN would not be visible by any other equipment connected to any of the other jacks in the landlord's router. The switch in the landlord's router would prevent this. Your assertion is incorrect. You are claiming a third router would solve a problem that does not exist.

Provided a tenant's router resided within their residence, that would firewall it, however it would still be double NAT'd and no one should have to ask a landlord to configure port forwarding when needed simply so they can access service needs as they arise. It's simply not a good scenario when a tenant should always be able to get their own WAN IP because it would be a separate service address when it's a legal apt - different if a roommate/AirBnB  scenario.

Either the tenant would have to ask the landlord to setup the port forward on the landlord's router or the landlord would have to give the tenant the password to the landlord's router. Also, I suppose the DMZ on the landlord's router could be set to the tenant's router. If any of these options are offered and are not acceptable to the tenant, then I assume the tenant would be free to get their own internet.

Yes, I don't want to access the tenant's LAN and I definitely don't want the tenant to be able to access my LAN.  I'm sorry that I didn't specify that I would have both routers under my physical control and I am specifying that the tenant needs to get their own wifi/router.  So the tenant has control over their own passwords for their router and their wifi, correct?  And I have the same if I do it correctly?  Again, mahalo to everyone that has provided a solution and/or input.  Aloha and happy holidays and be well.
